# What does the pattern "~도 ~나 ~ㄹ까?" mean?

Tags: grammar

What does a sentence like "~도 ~나 ~ㄹ까" mean?

For example:

> 그럼 나도 공부나 해볼까?
>
> 나도 영화나 볼까?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

~도

A particle meaning "too".

(이)나

A particle meaning "or". It is put after a noun and preceded by another noun, meaning "A or B". If nothing is after 나, it means the latter is "other things".

Ex: 영화나 볼까? Watch movies(or other things)?

ㄹ까 =>

1. It just denote future tense. The tone is softer but it is a bit authoritative.
2. What using as question, it could mean "What do you think".

So,

나도 영화나 볼까? 

May I watch movies too? (What do you think? It's ok if you want to watch other things)

Answer (score 4):

-도, meaning 'also', gives one an impression that the speaker is going to do something which he/she just heard/saw/witnessed. Can be roughly understood as 'imitating'. See this: http://krdic.naver.com/rescript_detail.nhn?seq=852

-(이)나, roughly meaning 'rather', looks like choosing this 'rather' than something else. For instance, 철수 was playing game with his friend and suddenly his friend said "I think it's time to study." Then 철수 says "그럼 나도 (게임 말고) 공부나 해볼까?" as the reply. This can be the most usual case, however sometimes '-(이)나' is used to express a bit of sarcasm, like 'Oh, is studying that easy, huh?'. There are many more definitions: http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=30364900, http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=6563400

-ㄹ까 is simply making an interrogative sentence. See this: http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=11418000